# How to resolve Return type error in Swift for a protocol method with associated type?

Tags: swift

I have a `protocol Request` with an associated type `Response` and an instance method `getToken` that returns a Publisher of associated type `Token` or an `Error`.

However, I'm getting a compilation error "Return type of instance method 'getToken' requires that 'RequestType.Response' conform to `any Token`".

How can I fix this error and make sure that the `RequestType.Response` conforms to `any Token`? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
func getToken<RequestType: Request>(_ request: RequestType) -> some Publisher<any Token, any Error> where RequestType.Response: Token {
  tokenClient.send(request)
}

// error：Return type of instance method 'getToken' requires that 'RequestType.Response' conform to 'any Token'
```

It works fine if I use `some Publisher<TokenWrapper, any Error>`, since there are several types of concrete token in my app. I don't want to repeat the line `.map(TokenWrapper.init)`.

```
struct TokenWrapper {
  let wrappedValue: any Token
}

// send<RequestType: Request>(_ request: RequestType, encoder: JSONEncoder? = nil, decoder: JSONDecoder = .init()) -> AnyPublisher<RequestType.Response, Error>

// current code works fine
func getToken<RequestType: Request>(_ request: RequestType) -> some Publisher<TokenWrapper, any Error> {
  tokenClient.send(request)
    .map(TokenWrapper.init)
}
func handle(_ pubilsher: some Publisher<TokenWrapper, any Error>) {
  publihsher
    ...
    ...
    .store(in: subscriptions)
}

// what I want the code looks like
func getToken<RequestType: Request>(_ request: RequestType) -> some Publisher<any Token, any Error> where RequestType.Response: Token {
  tokenClient.send(request)
}
func handle(_ pubilsher: some Publisher<any Token, any Error>) {
  publihsher
    .map(TokenWrapper.init)
    ...
    ...
    .store(in: subscriptions)
}
```

since the where clause do constraints `RequestType.Response` conforms to `Token`
why Xcode still complaints the error?

Comment: The entire proposed type `some Publisher<any Token, Error>` seems incoherent. It might be useful if you explained what real problem this is intended to solve.

Comment: Judging from the context, did you mean to return a `some Publisher<RequestType.Response, Error>` instead?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Does the description contain enough details now that I've added some information?@DávidPásztor

Comment: Do not divide your question into "edit" and "original question". Just edit the whole question to be better. There is no need to call out the fact that the question has been edited. Just write one, coherent, good question. (If we want to see the history of your edits, we can see it. There is no point making the question messier by trying to maintain the history in the question text itself.)

Comment: @matt I updated the question description as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely thinking of `any Token` here as meaning "any type that conforms to Token." That is not what it means. It means "an existential wrapper around a type that conforms to Token." So this:

```
some Publisher<any Token, any Error>
```

requires that the published type be literally `any Token` (the existential wrapper). Not "some concrete type that conforms to Token." Also, `any Token` does not itself conform to Token because existentials do not conform to their protocol. (You may bump into the fact that `any Error` does conform to Error, but this is a special-case exception handled by the compiler only for Error. It does not apply to any other protocol.)

To make this work, you need an explicit type eraser, which is exactly what you've created with TokenWrapper. Typically this would be named AnyToken instead, and it would conform to Token, but this is still the basic approach.

To match how Publisher works, you might want to rename this `.eraseToAnyToken`:

```
extension Publisher where Output: Token {
    func eraseToAnyToken() -> some Publisher<AnyToken, Failure> {
        self.map(AnyToken.init(token:))
    }
}

extension Publisher where Output == any Token {
    func eraseToAnyToken() -> some Publisher<AnyToken, Failure> {
        self.map(AnyToken.init(token:))
    }
}
```

And then you might have:

```
func getToken<RequestType: Request>(_ request: RequestType) -> some Publisher<AnyToken, any Error> {
    tokenClient.send(request)
        .eraseToAnyToken()
}
```

But you can't get rid of the type eraser with this design.

Separate from this question, but some advice:

I would strongly suggest rethinking Token as a protocol. Is that really correct? Or could Token be a concrete type that has multiple ways to initialize it? Doing that could dramatically simplify all of this. Creating too many inter-connected protocols and generics is a classic mistake, and networking stacks are a very common place people make this mistake by making the wrong parts of the system generic.

I would also strongly suggest looking at async/await rather than Combine for this. Many tricky things about Combine get much simpler when using the new system, and Apple has stepped back significantly from Combine.